# How to select first option by default in select box or drop down

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to display select box using directive. But my default option is not  display.

I do like this

```
<div>
    <select ng-init="userselected = vm.data[0]"
            ng-model="userselected"
            ng-options="option.name for option in vm.data">
    </select>
</div>
```

Here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/Q1e8u0okOa4looLcb2YO?p=preview

```
.controller('f',function($http){
        var l=this;
        $http.get('data.json').success(function(data){
          l.data=data;
        })
      })
```

**Can we load data before calling controller and loading the html file using resolve?**

Comment: Unclear question. Add a link to a documentation method as to what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JulianSoro thanks for help..I just need my first value should be selected in drop drop.which you do using $scope.tha is fine ..but can we load $http data before calling the controller of directive and html

Comment: if I load the data before calling the controller the I state way assign the value of default

Comment: I think what you mean is sending an AJAX call first, then after the data comes back compiling your angular app? Yes, that's *possible*, but I don't know why you would do that for a select menu

Comment: hmmm..I am trying to do my onwn..If i am not able to do then I will accept your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can we load data before **calling controller** and loading the html file using resolve?

Yes. The way to do that would be to *resolve* the dataset you want to expose onto your view **before** initialising the controller attached to said portion of the view.

I can think of three ways off of the top of my head;

- ui-router#resolve.
- ngRoute#resolve.
- defer compilation of the DOM attached to your controller.

#### ui-router#resolve

```
// state definition
.state('myState', function () {
  resolve: {
    dataset: function (Service) {
      return Service.getData();
    }
  },
  controller: 'Controller'
})
// controller definition
.controller('Controller', function (dataset) {
  this.dataset = dataset;
})
```

The resolved data will be available under the given name in the controller attached to the state definition (through the definition itself, or with a `ng-controller` at the **root** of your state template).

#### ngRoute#resolve

```
// route definition
.when('/path', {
  resolve: {
    dataset: function (Service) {
      return Service.getData();
    }
  },
  controller: 'Controller'
})
// controller definition
.controller('Controller', function (dataset) {
  this.dataset = dataset;
})
```

Pretty much the exact same way as the ui-router example.

#### ngIf

Defer the rendering of your template, by waiting for the promise to resolve.

```
.controller('outer', function ($timeout) {
  this.resolved = false;
  this.dataset  = [];

  $timeout(function () {
    this.resolved = true;
    this.dataset = [ {}, {} ];
  }.bind(this), 1500);
})
.controller('inner', function () {
  console.log('I just ran!');
})
```

---

```
<div ng-controller="outer as o">
  <div ng-controller="inner as i" ng-if="o.resolved">
    {{o.dataset}}
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle of the last solution](https://jsfiddle.net/phvjwfuv/)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `vm.data` is being populated asynchronously. When the view first loads and the ng-init is run, vm.data[0] is undefined, which is why it doesn't work. A quick fix is to add `ng-if="vm.data"` to the wrapper div so that the content within the ng-if is only added to the dom after vm.data is defined.

Also, Julian's answer is definitely a better solution. ng-init is usually a bad way to initialize values - it is much preferred that you initialize them in a controller.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out. So with angular you should be binding your model with the HTML elements using $scope.

http://plnkr.co/edit/dVI0MDC5k4AVSJAOMyy3?p=preview

The way I resolved this was to store your data to a scoped variable, and setting the init value to the first index in the array

```
controller('f',function($http, $scope){
    $scope.vm = null;
    $scope.userselected = null;
    $http.get('data.json').success(function(data){
      $scope.vm=data;
      $scope.userselected = $scope.vm[0];
    })
  })
```

And the changes to your HTML:

```
    <select ng-model="userselected"
            ng-options="option.name for option in vm">
    </select>
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do. What would be the point of not using $scope in this case?

Comment: I want to use vm ...I want to use controllerAs syntax

Comment: can we do do using resolve in directive.get data before calling html and controller or loading controller and html

Comment: This is one step closer, but you still need $scope for your model
http://plnkr.co/edit/dVI0MDC5k4AVSJAOMyy3?p=preview

Comment: thanks..I got it ..can we load data before calling directive controller and html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/5KlBnmnKzxvTU8R3zUaa?p=preview) on how to set the default value in select option.

Use: set the value using **ng-model**

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-select-with-default-values-production</title>  

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="defaultValueSelect">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="myForm">
    <label for="mySelect">Make a choice:</label>
    <select name="mySelect" id="mySelect"
      ng-options="option.name for option in data.availableOptions track by option.id"
      ng-model="data.selectedOption"></select>
  </form>
  <hr>
  <tt>option = {{data.selectedOption}}</tt><br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('defaultValueSelect', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
     availableOptions: [
       {id: '1', name: 'Option A'},
       {id: '2', name: 'Option B'},
       {id: '3', name: 'Option C'}
     ],
     selectedOption: {id: '3', name: 'Option C'} //This sets the default value of the select in the ui
     };
 }]);
})(window.angular);
```

Reference: [Using select with ngOptions and setting a default value](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove

```
 ng-init="userselected = vm.data[0]"
```

this init call from login.html

```
<div>
    <select ng-model="userselected"
            ng-options="option.name for option in vm.data">
    </select>
</div>
```

and modify your controller as -

```
 .controller('f',function($http,$scope){  // add $scope as a DI
    var l=this;
    $http.get('data.json').success(function(data){
      l.data=data;
      $scope.userselected = l.data[0];  // initalize or select first option
    })
  })
```

Hope this help!